# Flask template inheritance with CSS styles

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I've got a `base.html` file, which all other pages inherit from. Base links to `main.css` for style class definitions. However, so far this effect isn't being realized.

Base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {%block head%}
    {%endblock%}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}"/>

    {% if title %}
    <title> {{title}} </title>
    {%endif%}

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Task Master</h1>
    {%block body%}
    {%endblock%}
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{%extends "base.html"%}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
    <body>

    {%block body%}
    <div class="content">
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>Added</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        {%for task in tasks%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{task.content}}</td>
            <td>{{task.date_created.date()}}</td>
            <td>
              <a href="/delete/{{task.id}}">Delete</a>
              <br>
              <a href="/update/{{task.id}}">Update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
      </table>
      <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="content" id="content"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    {%endblock%}

  </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```css
.h1{
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And lastly, app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for,request,redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime,default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Task {self.id}>'

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        task_content = request.form['content']
        new_task = Todo(content=task_content)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "Failure to add content."
    else:
        tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
        return render_template('index.html',title='index',tasks=tasks)

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    task_to_delete = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)
    try:
        db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    except:
        return 'Task cannot be deleted'

@app.route('/update/<int:id>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def update(id):
    task = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        task.content = request.form['content']
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'Cannot update task'
    else:
        return render_template('update.html',task=task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What I'd like is for anything in an `<h1>` tag in base.html to be formatted according to the h1 definition on main.css. What do I need to do to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare `html` tag and other in the `index.html` since you've declared it in the `base.html`. So, your `index.html` should look something like this:

```html
{%extends "base.html"%}
{%block body%}
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Added</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    {%for task in tasks%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{task.content}}</td>
        <td>{{task.date_created.date()}}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="/delete/{{task.id}}">Delete</a>
          <br>
          <a href="/update/{{task.id}}">Update</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
  </table>
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="content" id="content"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Task"/>
  </form>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Thank you Suren, your answer is surely correct. However, suppose the index.html has other unique and specific CSS tags that need to be decorated differently from the base template, how do you go about doing it?

Comment: Hi @chibole! You can add extra stuff to templates using blocks: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance
You need to declare such blocks in base template and then override them in other templates which are using the base

Comment: Thank you , l appreciate your response.. It answers everything for me.